# Drag background div with the original div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

There are some divs with there background divs. By Clicking on settings the current divs hide and the background div displays. When I re arrange the divs (Divs are sorttable). The background divs retains its original position. And then when I want to see its background (Settings div)it rotates it from the old position

The script that rotates

```
      $('.flip_div').click(function() {
        var div1 = $(this).parent();
        var div2 = $('#'+$(this).attr('attached-with'));
        var toHide = div1.is(':visible') ? div1 : div2;
        var toShow = div2.is(':visible') ? div1 : div2;

        toHide.removeClass('flip in').addClass('flip out').hide();
        toShow.removeClass('flip out').addClass('flip in').show();
    });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/AFfNV/2/)**

Re arrange the divs then click on settings to see the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply wrap both back and front panels with a single element and make it a target of sorting.
So, HTML (see `<div class="single_panel">` around back and front section):

```
<div class="single_panel">
            <section id="pannel_front_1" class="pannel">
                <h4 class="pannel_title">Pannel 1</h4>
                <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_back_1" >Settings</span>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consequat.</p>
            </section>

            <section id="pannel_back_1" class="pannel" style="display:none">
                <h4 class="pannel_title">Back Side 1</h4>
                <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_front_1">back</span>
                    <p>Back Side.</p>
             </section>
        </div>
```

CSS for that new element:

```
.single_panel{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
}
```

And updated sortable init code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#sidebar" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".single_panel",
        }).disableSelection();
      });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AFfNV/3/

Answer (score 1):

Because of class=panel and sortable you  facing this issue So I have made two changes.
1. Added a div with class=panel and removed class=panel from all sections
2. Changed java script a little bit
HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<body>

<div id="pagewrap"> 
    <aside id="sidebar">
<div class="pannel">
        <section id="pannel_front_1" >
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Pannel 1</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_back_1" >Settings</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consequat.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="pannel_back_1" style="display:none">
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Back Side 1</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_front_1">back</span>
                <p>Back Side.</p>
         </section>
        </div>
        <div class="pannel">
        <section id="pannel_front_2" >
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Pannel 2</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_back_2" >Settings</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
        </section>

        <section id="pannel_back_2"  style="display:none">
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Back Side 2</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_front_2">back</span>
                <p>Back Side.</p>
         </section>
        </div>
                <div class="pannel">
        <section id="pannel_front_3" >
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Pannel 3</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_back_3" >Settings</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="pannel_back_3" style="display:none">
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Back Side 3</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_front_3">back</span>
                <p>Back Side.</p>
         </section>
        </div>
                     <div class="pannel">
        <section id="pannel_front_4" >
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Pannel 4</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_back_4" >Settings</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
        </section>

        <section id="pannel_back_4" style="display:none">
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Back Side 4</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_front_4">back</span>
                <p>Back Side.</p>
         </section>
        </div>
                            <div class="pannel">
        <section id="pannel_front_5" >
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Pannel 5</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_back_5" >Settings</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
        </section>

        <section id="pannel_back_5" style="display:none">
            <h4 class="pannel_title">Back Side 5</h4>
            <span class="flip_div div_menu" attached-with="pannel_front_5">back</span>
                <p>Back Side.</p>
         </section>
        </div>


        <!-- pannel end -->
    </aside>
    <!-- sidebar ends-->


</div>
<!-- pagewrap ends-->

</body>
</html>
```

java script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#sidebar" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".pannel",
        }).disableSelection();
      });

      $('.flip_div').click(function() {               
        var div1 = $(this).parent();
        var div2 = $('#'+$(this).attr('attached-with'));

         $(div1).removeClass('flip in').addClass('flip out').hide();          
         $(div2).removeClass('flip out').addClass('flip in').show();          

    });

});
```

And it's done. Try it out.